# How to post on FB page with Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am trying to post something on the FB page. I have successfully integrated the code and I can open FB in my app. I am using the following code:

```
let vc = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
vc.setInitialText("Hurray! Welcome to My App")
presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

When I try to run this, I am facing error as No fb app is installed in the device.

[image]

I want to post on FB page and I don't want the users to have FB app in their mobile. Is it possible? If so how?

Comment: you have to do login with facebook. from the settings app.

Comment: Be aware that if the Facebook app *is* installed you can't pre-populate text http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890747/ios-how-to-share-text-and-image-on-social-networks/29891228#29891228

Comment: @Paulw11 so if the user dont have fb in their device, what are my options then?

Comment: If they don't have the Facebook app then it will work as long as the user has added an account as per @AshishKakkad's answer

Comment: @AAA did you checked with login through Facebook in settings ? it is working for you?

Comment: @Paulw11 You are correct there is some problem with iOS 8.x

Comment: @AshishKakkad Yes, it is working for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an error. Don't worry. 
This is an message to display you that you have not logged in to the Facebook.

Go to the Settings App > Facebook

[image]

Login from here.

[image]

You are not getting error. It just a warning message.