# Why do some users get a different Facebook Share Sheet Dialog box than others

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, fbsdk, fbsdksharekit

[FB Dialog Missing og: Title](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WsFqR.png)

[image: Desired FB Dialog including og: Title]

When some users share to facebook their dialog box is missing the auto-populated og: title and the image is displayed like a polaroid rather than a banner.

let content = FBSDKShareLinkContent()
        content.contentURL = NSURL(string: longUrlString)
        FBSDKShareDialog.showFromViewController(self, withContent: content, delegate: nil)

Comment: That image is the desired dialog box, I had trouble showing multiple images.

Comment: Facebook A/B testing?

Comment: This week something happened with facebook ios sdk, my app was working fine when posting imageURL but from this week (or the last one) nothing is shown and I could not find solution for that.

Comment: It depends whether they have the Facebook app installed. If you don't have the app then you get the in-built iOS share sheet. If you have the app installed then you get the one from the app. The app does not allow pre-generated text. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29890747/ios-how-to-share-text-and-image-on-social-networks/29891228#29891228

Comment: Where do you expect the title to be?